# Recursion: simple spiral with python turtle

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to recreate a function `spiral()` using recursion that takes the parameters `initLen` (pixel length of first side), `N` (angle connecting segments), and `mult` (a float amount indicating how much bigger/smaller each segment should be after each turn - ex: `mult = 0.5` means each segment would be half the length of the previous). The drawing should stop when the segment length reaches less than 1 or greater than 500.

example of desired output for `spiral( 100, 90, 0.9 )`:

[image: desired output]

I have attempted this:

```
def spiral( initLen, N, mult ):

if initLen> 500:
    return
elif initLen< 1:
    return
else:
    pendown()
    forward(initLen)
    left(360.0/N)
    spiral((initLen*mult),angle, mult)
```

Thinking the only thing changing is segment length (by order of the multiplier) each turn.

My program output for `spiral( 20, 90, 0.9 )` is....

[image: bad spiral]

not quite similar to above...

Any hints?

Comment: You've mixed up what the second argument means - whether it's a number of degrees to turn, or a number of turns before you're pointing the way you initially pointed.

Comment: You should repost this as an answer because that was the root of the problem! I clearly need to retake elementary school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example invocation you posted (`spiral( 100, 90, 0.9 )`) seems to treat the second parameter as the degree of each turn whereas you treat it as the number of turns to make a complete 360 degree turn in your code.

Either change the call to `spiral(20, 4, 0.9)` or the turn to `left(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

inside the function you call

```
forward(initialLength)
```

but the variable referenced in the function call and in the rest of the function is

```
initLen
```

so probably the value of initialLength is static and not what you want.

Comment: My bad, I shortened the variable names for readability when I posted, looks like I missed a spot. Fixed it - unfortunately that isn't the problem

Comment: too bad, that would have been an easy fix. i think @user2357112 got it though in the comment above